# Is it possible to go back to the line where an error was encountered in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling

I'm trying to find a smarter way to allow a user to retry or continue from where error was encountered, and I know the stacktrace in Exception class gives some information about where an error occurred, is there some way I can try to *time travel* back to the error line maybe after I tell the user to do something?

**EDIT:**

---

From what I've seen, VB seems to have something like `On Error Resume Next`. I guess I'm looking for something similar to this but can be manually handled for C#.

Comment: I assume the exception is a bug in your program, so find a way to fix it instead of "travelling back".

Comment: You will need to narrow this question down. What kind of "error" are you talking about? Give an example.

Comment: I know what you mean, It will jump to the exception handling, not where the exception occured. It's very hard to debug.

Comment: The errors are file access errors. Sometimes, I need people to close files and try again, but I'm writing a program that does a lot of file operations and I am trying to see if it's possible to avoid adding different try and catch everywhere.

Comment: @GrantWinney: Quite helpful suggestion, but these errors can actually be RANDOM at times. One moment a file/folder may be locked/inaccessible, the next second it's open.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're looking for a way to manage exceptions and the topic is really really complex...
About the time travel machine, there's the intellitrace in VS-Ultimate, excepted that I really don't see the benefit of that at a enduser point of view.
For example, let's say you upload a file and for some reason the upload fail, it could be great to offer the user to retry the update, but that opportunity have to be managed by you in your code, with for example a try/catch and your logic in the catch to restart the upload... But I really don't know any generic method to try/catch everything and allow the user to retry, and, IMHO, it's better like that. 
If it's a business exception, you know how to manage it. If it's a technical bug, you can surround touchy code with try/catch and do the appropriate thing after.

Answer (score 0):

The exception shows where the code *broke*, but that doesn't mean it's where the error was introduced.

For example:

```
var someString = "";  // Assumed someString will always be nonnull
someString = DoSomeWork();  // OOPS! Due to a bug, this returns null in some cases.
Console.WriteLine(someString.Length);
```

The error appears on line three, but the source of the bug (or malformed user input, etc.) was on the previous line.

### Instead:

Pick explicit *recovery points* in your code where you can restart if something goes wrong and wrap it in a try/catch+loop. In the case of malformed user input:

```
do
{
    try
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var myNumber = Int32.Parse(input);
        DoSomethingWithNumber(myNumber);

        break;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Optional error handling, explain the error,
        // tell the user to retry, logging, etc.
        // If possible, catch something more specific
        // than Exception (like ArgumentException, 
        // FormatException, etc.).
    }
} while(true);
```

`On Error Resume Next`, while it may have its occasional use, is far too easily abused so I'm sure it purposefully wasn't included in .Net.